# How Do I solve the below congruence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

let $x$ be an integer, I want to solve the following quadratic equation satisfying the below condition :

$ 5x^2+40x+100=4 \mod m$ , with $m$ is integer , such that $m=6,7,8,9$

and $ \; 5x^2+40x+100=0 \mod m$ with $m =2,4,5$

and $\; 5x^2+40x+100=1\mod m$, with $m=3$ .

I have tried the Chinese remainder theorem but I didn't succeed, Any way?

**Note**:I have edited the equation because i have got a wrong typo without changing the meaning of question

Comment: You can solve quadratic congruences using the quadratic formula, but being careful to interpret the quotient as multiplication by the inverse and the square root as modular square root. That will not work for $\bmod 6$, since the quadratic formula does not work modulo $2$, but you can use the quadratic formula mod 3 and then do it manually mod 2 and use the CRT to get the answer modulo 6.

Comment: $5x^2+4x+1\equiv0\bmod2$ is very easy:  it's $x^2=1\bmod2$, so $x\equiv1\bmod2$

Comment: I'll revise my comment to accord with the edited question:  $5x^2+40x+100\equiv0\bmod2$ is very easy:  it's $x^2\equiv0\bmod2$, so $x\equiv0\bmod2$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Solve equation(s)  modulo primes first, i.e. modulo $2, 3, 5, 7$, check whether the discriminant is a square.

Modulo $6$, from a solution $\alpha\bmod 2$ and a solution $\beta\bmod 3$, you can deduce a solution $\bmod 6$ using a Bézout's identity between $2$ and $3$ (e.g. $3-2=1$):
$$\xi =3\alpha-2\beta\bmod 6.$$
For solutions mod. $2^3$ and $3^2$, you deduce them from the solutions $\bmod 2$ and $3$ tespectivelu=y using *Hensel's lifting*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I had a wrong typo in my equation i have edited it

Answer (score 0):

(1) For $m=6,$ write the equation as $6x^2-x^2+40x-96=0,$ which becomes $x^2-4x-=0$ modulo $6.$ This factors to give $x(x-4)=0,$ from which you may proceed as usual. For $m=7,8,9,$ similar maneuvers work.

(2) This is particularly easy, as it reduces respectively to $x^2=0,\,x^2=0$ and $0=0$ respectively modulo $2,4,5.$

(3) This reduces to $2x^2+x=0,$ which also factors nicely, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , Pleas I had a wrong typo for my equation, I have edited it without changing any of the titled conditions

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Accordingly edited.

Answer (score 0):

In my Humbel Guess :let $y=5x^2+40x+100=(2x+10)^2+x^2$ , The Nice particular solution for that equation satisfying the titled  conditions is $y=2020$ and $2020$ can be written as $2020=16^2+42^2$ , now $42=2x+10$ implies $x=16$